How to make things bigger or zoom on VSCode web?
On normal VSCode, we can simply do CTRL + or Control - and Control 0 to control zoom.
On VSCode web, this zooms the entire page like a picture. Also there's no such options:
View > Appearance > Zoom In (Ctrl+=) - increase the zoom level.
View > Appearance > Zoom Out (Ctrl+-) - decrease the zoom level.
View > Appearance > Reset Zoom (Ctrl+Numpad0) - reset the zoom level to 0.

as mentioned in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/accessibility
So how to make things bigger? Not the editor font, the actual buttons and everything for readability
